# unresolved import in python opencv samples

Tags: python, opencv, pydev

I am having problem running the opt_flow.py in /opencv/samples/python2.
In /samples/python everything is okay. But in python2, there seems something missing.

The python version: 2.7.3
IDE: pyDev in Eclipse

running opt_flow.py from
https://github.com/jonmarimba/OpenCVMirror/blob/ff81e19a7a12764c657e2765d69ef166065f5e61/opencv/samples/python2/opt_flow.py

Below are from the code snippet:

```
    import cv2, cv2.cv as cv
    import video
    from common import anorm2, draw_str
    from time import clock
    ...
```

and there comes errors..

```
    Description    Resource  Path                           Location Type
    Unresolved import: video    optical_flow.py /practice/test  line 9  PyDev Problem
    Unresolved import: draw_str optical_flow.py /practice/test  line 10 PyDev Problem
    Unresolved import: anorm2   optical_flow.py /practice/test  line 10 PyDev Problem
```

which I didn't found any related solution to this error, can anyone help?

Comment: Please post the code which threw the error (this code you have posted obviously couldn't throw the error you have posted). Also, please post the version of Python.

Comment: the code is directly copied from the sample code with the link above. I think it is the python library problem but don't have a idea of knowing what I am missing...

Comment: Sorry I solve the problem this morning. I pull this piece of code from the /opencv/samples/python2 folder but did not notice there was other files need to include together. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem so here's the answer just to make it clear to others:

The opencv examples import other files in the same folder. The video.py file is in the same place you found the sample you were running. If you copy one of the examples out, you will also need to copy out other files that it imports, including video.py, common.py, and others.

Comment: Or add the sample folder to your PYTHONPATH.